# Determine the transformations of $\frac{2-z}{iz-2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Determine the transformations of $\frac{2-z}{iz-2}$.

I know there must be a way to get rid of one of the z's, but I do not know how. The closest bit of information is that we can express $\frac{2z+2}{iz+1}$ as $-2i+\frac{2+2i}{iz+1}$, but I do not know how my professor got to that. Once I get to one z, I know to convert to polar form and from there I can determine it. I just need to get rid of a z.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by determining the transformation of $\frac{2-z}{iz-2}$?

Comment: $-2i+\dfrac{2+2i}{iz+1}=\dfrac{-2i(iz+1)+2+2i}{iz+1}=\dfrac{2z+2}{iz+1}$

Comment: There are many ways to obtain that transformation composing translations, rotations, homotheties and inversions. One way to get one such composition can be to compute the quotient ant remainder of $-z+2$ divided by $iz-2$. The quotient is $i$ and the remainder is $2+2i$. This means that $\frac{2-z}{iz-2}=i+\frac{2+2i}{iz-2}$. Now it is just a question of following the order of operations. First $z$ is multiplied by $i$ (rotation of $\pi/2$ with respect to the origin), then from the result one subtracts $2$ (translation parallel to $-2$), then one computes reciprocal (inversion ...

Comment: ... with respect to the unit circle followed by reflection with respect to the real line), the one multiplies by $2+2i=\sqrt{8}e^{i\pi/4}$ (homothety with respect to the origin with ratio $\sqrt{8}$ and rotation of $\pi/4$ with respect to the origin). Finally one adds $i$, which is a translation one unit up.